# What's the correct syntax for calling query.getObjectwithId(<id>, error())?

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

Environment: 
Parse SDK version 1.90

Swift 2.1

Scenario:

Attempting to catch a query throw of an bad-query exception.  I got the query template but I don't know the 2nd (error) parameter format.

I can't figure out what the syntax for the error parameter should be:

[image]

---

I removed the 'if' per suggestion, but got another compiler error:
[image]

Remedy?

Comment: did you figure it out? I have the same issue

Comment: I'm sensing that this is a Parse.com bug.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the error parameter is correct. However `objectWithId` does not return an Optional so wrapping it in a `if let` is not necessary and will cause an error (the 2nd error in your case).

This compiles without errors:

```
do {
    let object = try query.getObjectWithId("OBJECT_ID", error: ())
    print(object)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Regarding the `Editor placeholder in source file` error: That's strange one. Did you copy that code somewhere and paste it into Xcode? Try re-writing the code by hand. I did not get that error and I'm sure that it is unrelated to the syntax of the error parameter.

Comment: I'm still getting the complaint: "Initializer for conditional binding must have an Optional type, not a PFObject type".  This appears to be a Parse.com bug.

Comment: Have you removed the 'if' before the 'let'?

Comment: It slipped my mind.   Okay... got ride of the 'if'.... apparently solved that compilation issue but got another issue: "variable used within its own initial value" (see modified query above).

Comment: Can you post the line of code wehre you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was using an older parse.com SDK (v1.8.2).   So I've updated to v. 1.9.0.

I got assorted Swift 2.1 syntax errors after I updated the parse.com frameworks.

So the remedy is the revised APIs using the new Swift 2.1 error handling paradigm:

```
do {
     let videoObject = try query.getObjectWithId("")
   } catch {
     print("")
}
```